# Error with File Connector in a file transfer method

Tags: file, wso2, wso2-esb, wso2-enterprise-integrator, file-connection

Good day, I am experiencing the below error after deploying my CapApp on EI 7.1.0

"WARN {FtpClientFactory$FtpConnectionFactory} - Invalid connection timeout null. Set the connectionTimeout as 5000. (default)
[2022-10-13 15:50:12,626]  WARN {FtpClientFactory$FtpConnectionFactory} - Invalid connection retry count null. Set the connectionRetryCount as 5. (default)
[2022-10-13 15:50:12,626] ERROR {ListFiles} - Error while performing file:listFiles for folder ftp://ftp-user:***@192.168.1.36:21/Incoming/In org.apache.commons.vfs2.FileSystemException: Could not connect to FTP server on "192.168.1.36"."

Any assistance will be much appreciated.

Comment: I have attempted to add a connection timeout to the ListFile file connector, But it gets removed right after

Comment: Please post the xml code from your implementation so we can see your configuration